# How to save a style file in TeXShop?

Tags: texshop, package-writing

When I try to save a .sty file in TeXShop, I get the message "You cannot save this document with extension “.sty” at the end of the name. The required extension is “.tex”." Of course, I could change the extension later, or just use a separate text editor for .sty files. But I thought part of the point of a LaTeX package like TeXShop is to have everything you need arranged conveniently in one package. I'm running Version 5.04 in macOS 11.5.2.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running TeXShop 5.04 on macOS 10.15.7 and I can save `sty` file with no problem. With your document loaded, select File -> Save to bring up the save dialog box. At the bottom of that box, beneath the preview area, look for File Format and select `sty` from the available formats, name your file, and click Save.

Note that a `sty` file is just a plain ASCII file so it's not really a different format from, say, a `tex` file so TeXShop's terminology is a bit confusing.

Comment: What I can't do is leave the File Format as `tex` but save the file as `filename.sty`.  That may have been OP's problem.

Comment: I wonder if that's a bug?